# Is it possible return paginated result usin Stream API in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, pagination, java-stream

So, I have a `Stream` with some objects and I need to return paginated result from `Stream`. For example from 2nd to 4th elements.

```
Stream<String> strs = Stream.of("qwe", "asd", "zxc", "rty", "fgh", "vbn");
```

And return only from 2nd to 4th elements: `asd, zxc, rty`.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The javadoc is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use [`Stream#skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip(long)) in conjunction with [`Stream#limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)):

```
strs.skip(1).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will output the following:

```
asd
zxc
rty
```

In this example, `Stream#skip` skips the first element of the `Stream` and `Stream#limit` limits the remaining `Stream` to three elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `skip` and `limit`

```
Stream<String> strs = Stream.of("qwe", "asd", "zxc", "rty", "fgh", "vbn");
String result=strs.skip(1).limit(3).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

> asd zxc rty